# How to get button text with ng-model in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started to work with Angular, it seems good to implement.
I always use `ng-model` to get text from `textfield`. Can I get the button text with help of `ng-model` or something else?

For example this is button

```
<button class="common btnDarkGrey">Do it</button>
```

and I want to get `Do it` with Angular.

Comment: Why do you need to get the button text? Does it changed after it was initialized? button text is usually one way data-binding, only from model to view.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ng-bind` to bind the data in your controller to the button.

```
<button ng-bind="buttonNameVariable"></button>
```

Then in your controller you will have a variable named `scope.buttonNameVariable="Do it"`

You can use the variable in the controller, and retrieve it with the variable. You use ng-model only for input fields in html, not for buttons for example.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
$scope.buttonText = 'Do It' //in the JS
<button>{{buttonText}}</button> <!-- in the HTML -->
```

or:

```
<button ng-init="buttonText = 'Do It'">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

Then you have the text of the button in the `buttonText` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind putting jQuery codes in angular, this could be done:

```
$('button.common').click(function(){
   console.log($('button.common').html())
});
```